# Threads inside a qt class

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I have this class inside a qt application that has some data defined:

```
class TableView:public QWidget 
{
  Q_OBJECT

  public:TableView (QWidget * parent = 0);

  std::vector < float >  arr;
```

and some class functions and so on.. 
Now I want to add a socket server in another thread (posibly from inside this class) that is able to access data from this class when it recives something from the socket, calculate
new data and return.

For the test I used:

```
  //defines
  DWORD WINAPI SocketHandler(void* lp);
  DWORD WINAPI starttremeshserver(void* lp);


  CreateThread(0,0,&starttremeshserver, (void*)csock , 0,0);
```

This works. Now I need something easy and platform independent. Maybe something with qthread since I am working in qt.

So the question is, can I make a new thread function inside a class that can access class data. ty

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Qt provides everything you need. Your needs are as follows:

1. Thread-safe (serialized) access to the data members of the `TableView` class.
2. Networking primitives.
3. Flexibility to move network access to a separate thread.

You are probably receiving data from the network, and want to update the `arr` member. You'd do it like so:

1. Create a `QObject`-derived class, say `Processor`, that has a slot that sets up the network connection (probably a `QTcpServer`). Upon a connection, use `QTcpSocket` to exchange data. Make sure all your data handling is done in slots in the class. When you have new values to update in the vector, simply `emit` some signal, like `hasFloat(int,float)`.
2. Add a `setFloat(int,float)` slot in the `TableView`.
3. Connect the `setFloat` signal from the instance of `Processor` to your `TableView`.

At this point, everything runs in the GUI thread, but the code is non-blocking since you never wait for network data; you respond to the signals emitted by `QTcpServer` and `QTcpSocket`. You can leave it like that if you wish.

Having the `Processor` class run in a separate thread, if your benchmarking shows that your main thread is CPU bound, is then trivial:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
   bool separateThread = true;
   QApplication app(argc, argv);
   TableView view;
   Processor proc;
   connect(&proc, SIGNAL(hasFloat(int,float)), &view, SLOT(setFloat(int,float)));
   QThread thread;
   if (separateThread) {
      thread.start();
      proc.moveToThread(&thread);
   }
   view.show();
   const bool rc = app.exec();
   if (thread.isRunning()) {
      thread.exit(); // tells the event loop in the thread to bail out
      thread.wait(); // waits for the above to finish
   }
   return rc;
}
```

There's this misconception that spreading things across threads somehow magically makes them better. Threads are a solution to a particular problem: CPU-boundedness of the computations being done, and blocking APIs. If your processing is trivial, you are not likely to be CPU bound. Qt provides nonblocking, asynchronous networking. Thus, usually, spinning a second thread is entirely unnecessary.

You must show real numbers first to show you otherwise. Else you're buying into the *cargo cult of threading*: oh, it's networking, it must go into a separate thread. Nope, not necessarily. Measure first. Understand what you're doing.

The reason for thread safety in the above code is as follows: when you move the `Processor` instance to a different thread, Qt will reconnect all signal-slot connections using `Qt::QueuedConnection` type. Thus, when `Processor` emits `hasFloat`, it will internally cause an event to be queued in the event queue of the thread where `TableView` lives -- the GUI thread, in this case. When the event loop spins (here it'd be the application's event loop) -- it'll pick up the event and execute a call to `TableView::setFloat`. This ensures that the access to the `arr` data member is serialized and there are is no possibility of concurrent access from multiple threads.

Comment: I found this nice example for my QTcpServer:[link](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/network-threadedfortuneserver.html) I will try to incorporate data exchange next, ty all!

Answer (score 1):

Qt has threading support as can be found [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/threads.html).

In addition to threads and accessing the data, you'll need synchronization for thread-safe code. This is called pthread mutex in linux, and in Qt its called QMutex as mentioned [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/threads-synchronizing.html).

You can find the Qt networking primitives [here](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/network-programming.html).

Using the Qt implementation of these threading and networking primitives will be portable, so should work for you on windows.

Regarding your question about creating a thread function from a class that accesses data on that class, the answer is yes. Instead of creating a thread function, it would be better to create a thread object, namely a QThread. When you create the thread object, you'll need to pass a reference to the instance of said class, which will allow the thread to access the class instance.

Answer (score 1):

I'd personally look for more high level socket support, something based on boost perhaps, anyway for threads you can use `<thread>` in C++11.

To answer your specific question:

```
class Foo
{
private:
    void spinthread()
    {
        thread t([this] { 
            this->bar = 12;
        });
    } 

private:
   int bar;
}
```

If you're using Win32 threads API, the thread proc has a parameter which you can use to pass your instance to during the CreateThread call.